# How to build QGraphicsView like components in Java

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, swt, simulation

I need to build a simulation application in Java and i need to build QGraphicsView like component in  Java Swing or SWT.

My requirements are

1. building map
2. enabling mice object to  go around so - called map.
3. zoomin/zoomout
4. rotating coordinate system like
   this.

[image]

I have mainly  two  questions.

First question is  which (Swing, SWT or Something else) is more suitable for developing this.

Latter is you know any open source library like QGraphicsView except than Qt Jambi

Maybe it can be weird question but i want to  learn your  opinions coming from your  experience.

Any idea  will be appreciated

thanks

--İbrahim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Would suggest using GEF or Draw2d.

GEF is designed for Diagram creation, so if you need more complex diagram support, then that is good choise. GEF is highly expandable and usable in many many different solutions.
More information of GEF here:
http://www.eclipse.org/gef/

If you think GEF is not totally what you need, then there is Draw2D. Draw2D is very good graphical canvas framework. GEF uses Draw2d in background, but Draw2D doesn't depend on GEF.
Draw2D provides good canvas features, very similar to QGraphicsView.
More information of Draw2D can be found here:
http://www.eclipse.org/gef/draw2d/index.php